# Check program history in Windows Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, logging, history

Is there a way within Windows Vista to check program history, much like how a web browser logs  web pages that you have visited? Let's I wanted to see when `chrome.exe` was started. I'm not looking for any fancy details such as the programs up time or usage stats, just when it was opened and closed.

Is that possible, even if I don't have any prior software installed to log this information?

Comment: There is a thing name `Event Viewer`, but it only displays [some information](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/What-information-appears-in-event-logs-Event-Viewer) about a program, not all history, [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-Event-Viewer) is how it can be opened in Vista.

Comment: No, this information is not logged by default.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is **no**.

You can write a script that takes a snapshot of running processes, or updates whenever a new process is launched (the implementation details/requirements are up to you) but there is nothing within the OS that shows when an app was launched/terminated.